# Invalid authentication info error when using Azure AD and Azure Storage PUT API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-rest-api, azure-rbac

I'm trying to upload a file to a container in Azure Storage using Azure Active Directory (AAD) Authentication and REST API's. I can't figure out what is missing in the workflow below, but it always fails.

**How it works:**

0. A service principal (SP) was created in AAD
1. A `client_secret` was generated for this SP
2. `Contributor` role added to the Storage Account for the SP, **at the Storage Account-level**

   - Side question: Can the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role be scoped down to the *Container-level* instead of granting at the Account-level?
3. Sample authentication request:

   - Method: `GET`
   - URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token`
   - Body: `x-www-form-urlencoded`

     - `grant_type`: `client_credentials`
     - `client_id`: `<client_id>`
     - `scope`: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`
     - `client_secret`: `<client_secret>`
   - Header(s):

     - `content-type`: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
4. Sample auth. response:

   - Status: 200
   - Body:

```json
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "<auth_token>"
}
```

5. No problem thus far. The `<auth_token>` from this request is then used to send a PUT request to upload file to Azure Storage Container
6. Sample upload request:

   - Method: `PUT`
   - URL: `https://<stg-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<file-name>.json`
   - Body: `binary`

     - `<file-name>.json`
   - Header(s):

     - `x-ms-blob-type`: `BlockBlob`
     - `x-ms-version`: `2020-04-08`

       - Required for AAD auth (at least per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services#requests-authorized-using-azure-ad-shared-key-or-shared-key-lite))
     - `Authentication`: `Bearer <auth_token>`
7. Sample upload response:

   - Status: 401
   - Body:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:<guid>
Time:2022-09-26T18:29:27.4477615Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature validation failed. Signature verification failed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

**Tried:**

- Removing the `Bearer` keyword from the Authentication header

  - Results in Status 403
- Changing the `x-ms-version` header from `2017-11-09` to `2020-04-08`

  - No change

**Questions**

1. What is missing here?
2. Where is this covered in the documentation?

---

**EDIT1**

1. RE: "What is missing here?"

   - Thank you @gaurav-mantri, your suggested worked!
   - I changed the `scope` header to `https://storage.azure.com/.default` in the auth request.
   - The subsequent upload request responded with status 201.
2. RE: "Can you help me find this referenced in the docs?"

   - Thank you again @gaurav-mantri, here is the [doc ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#use-oauth-access-tokens-for-authentication)

Comment: Did you give `Contributor` access to your SP or `Storage Blob Data Contributor` (in step 2)?

Comment: Also try by changing the scope from `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` to `https://storage.azure.com/.default` in step 3.

Comment: Yes, `Contributor` access to SP to remove permissions from being an issue while testing. I *want* to grant `Storage Blob Data Contributor` on only the Container ("Side question")

Comment: Regarding #2, please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#use-oauth-access-tokens-for-authentication

Comment: The term `https://storage.azure.com/.default` is not present on the page. Looking for a reference to the `scope` value somewhere in official documentation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet#get-an-access-token-from-azure-ad.

Comment: Thank you very much! ([REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet#azure-storage-resource-id))

Comment: Hi @ericOnline if you solve your issue kindly post as an answer so that it will be helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem.

Comment: Please see **EDIT1** in OP. It tells you exactly what I changed in the original request.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one service principal **Test** and added **`Contributor`** role to it at storage account level as below:

[image]

I generated the access token with **same parameters** as you like below:

[image]

When I use the above access token to upload file via **`PUT`** request, I am getting **same error** as you like this:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to add **`Storage Blob Data Contributor`** role to your service principal at **Azure Storage container level** as below:

[image]

Now, I generated access token by changing scope to **`https://storage.azure.com/.default`**  like this:

[image]

With this token, I am able to **upload file to Azure Storage container** successfully as below:

[image]

When I checked **Azure Portal**, file got uploaded successfully like this:

[image]

If you generated the token by changing the scope to [**https://storage.azure.com/.default**](https://storage.azure.com/.default)  and did not assign **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role, you will get **`403 error`** like below:

[image]

So, make sure to grant **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to service principal before generating access token.

Comment: The Service Principal had `Contributor` access on the Storage Account (step 2 in OP). The answer was the `scope` header on the auth request. Once I changed that, the upload request worked.